# How to check whether iPhone and apple watch are connected and their distance?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I realize that this question has been asked before but most answers are from 2015 and I had no success with their tips.

I'm trying to achieve a functionality like Lookout app that notifies you when you are leaving your iPhone behind.

I've tried using CoreBluetooth but I can only detect the watch if the watch is with the screen turned on.

WCSession to check reachability is good for file transfers check but not to achieve this functionality.

Any suggestions?

Thanks